# How to build a chat app with flutter and mysql?

Tags: mysql, flutter, chat

I am new to flutter and I want to transfer a chat website into an app but the problem that it depends on a mysql database and I have no experience in it, So I searched for ways to build it but didn't find anything, all the tutorials are about firebase so I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way for you that is used to socket.io plugins and use from nodejs for server-side

Comment: Is there a tutorial for that, because I am really new to all of this

Comment: yes this link learned it all https://medium.com/flutter-community/realtime-chat-app-flutter-node-js-socket-io-e298cd27fb06